# Какой корень в слове "довольны"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, морфемика, морфемный-разбор, корень-слова

"Доволь" или " воль"? Или какой-то другой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Дово́льно** - нареч. от *до* и *во́ля*.

*Этимологический словарь русского языка Макса Фасмера*

Следовательно,  изначально был корень -вол-.

**Довольный**. Общеславянское образование от *довълъ* (см. довлеть). Первоначальное значение – "достаточный".

Заимствование из старославянского, где образовано от существительного довълъ – "достаток, имущество". Значение этого глагола – "быть достаточным", однако в народной этимологии по ассоциации с давить и получило значение "тяготеть над кем-нибудь или над чем-нибудь". Существительное довълъ образовано от той же основы, что и **велеть, воля,** довольный, продовольствие.

*Этимологический словарь Крылова*

**Дово́льн/ый.**

*Морфемно-орфографический словарь Тихонова*

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/997/%d0%95%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0 Не очень поняла, получается, корень -вол- ?..

Comment: Изначально - да. В современном русском языке корень довольн-.